# How can I enable PHP's mysqli extension in a Nitrous.io box?

Tags: nitrousio

I cannot manage to install/enable the mysqli extension in my PHP-Nitrous.io-box. Reading the phpinfo() output, I see that mysql and PDO are available, but not mysqli.

Help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

[PHPInfo() raw output](http://pastebin.com/N0fPfGSa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the solution is to uninstall the current version and install again from source. It may take some time, around 15 - 20 minutes.

`parts uninstall php5`

`parts install php5 --source`

wait for it...

`parts stop apache2`

`parts start apache2`

check with your phpinfo()

PS: this is a temporary solution. `mysqli` extension may have been already implemented globally.

Comment: Just as an update, we have updated the PHP5 binary with Autoparts and you can install it without the `--source` tag now. Just run `parts install php5` and the latest version will install with mysqli.